# Why fine-tuning BERT mlm on specific domain doesn't work? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, pre-trained-model, fine-tuning

I'm new. I'm trying to fine-tuned a BERT MLM (bert-base-uncased) on a target domain. Unfortunately, results are not good.

Before fine-tuning, the pre-trained model fills the mask of a sentence with words in line of human expectations. 
E.g. *Wikipedia is a free online [MASK], created and edited by volunteers around the world.* 
The most probable prediction are *encyclopedia* (score: 0.650) and *resource* (score:0.087).

After fine-tuning, the prediction are completely wrong. Often stopwords are predicted as result. 
E.g. *Wikipedia is a free online [MASK], created and edited by volunteers around the world.* 
The most probable prediction are *the* (score: 0.052) and *be* (score:0.033).

I experimented with different epochs (from 1 to 10) and different datasets (from a few MB to a few GB) but I got the same issue. What am I doing wrong? I'm using the following code, I hope you can help me.

```
from transformers import AutoConfig, AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForMaskedLM

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', output_hidden_states=True)
model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_config(config)  # BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained(path)

from transformers import LineByLineTextDataset

dataset = LineByLineTextDataset(tokenizer=tokenizer,
                                file_path="data/english/corpora.txt", 
                                block_size = 512)

from transformers import DataCollatorForLanguageModeling

data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=True, mlm_probability=0.15)

from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments

training_args = TrainingArguments(output_dir="output/models/english",
                                 overwrite_output_dir=True,
                                 num_train_epochs=5,
                                 per_gpu_train_batch_size=8,
                                 save_steps = 22222222,
                                 save_total_limit=2)

trainer = Trainer(model=model, args=training_args, data_collator=data_collator, train_dataset=dataset)

trainer.train()
trainer.save_model("output/models/english")

from transformers import pipeline

# Initialize MLM pipeline
mlm = pipeline('fill-mask', model="output/models/english", tokenizer="output/models/english")

# Get mask token
mask = mlm.tokenizer.mask_token

# Get result for particular masked phrase
phrase = f'Wikipedia is a free online {mask}, created and edited by volunteers around the world'

result = mlm(phrase)

# Print result
print(result)
```